# how to remove space and repeated digit from string

Tags: php, mysql

How to remove space and repeated digit from string. My piece of code is,

```
<?php
if(@$get_colors_l > 0)
{
    while($get_colors_r = mysqli_fetch_array($get_colors))
    {
        echo $get_colors_r["color"];  //result is 1,2 1
        $color = explode(",", $get_colors_r["color"]); 

        foreach($color as $color_code)
        {   
            echo $color_code; // result is 1 2 1
            $get_single_color = $filter -> getSingleColor($color_code);

            while($get_single_color_r = mysqli_fetch_array($get_single_color))
            {
?>
                <p class="inline1"><button style="background-color:<?php echo $get_single_color_r["color_code"]; ?>; height:25px; width:25px; border:none"></button></p>
<?php
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now the result of above code is `1 2 1`. I want it as `1 2`. I want to make repeated digit as single.

How to done this. I have no idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After search a lot finaly i have got the answer.

```
            <?php
            if(@$get_colors_l > 0)
            {
                while($get_colors_r = mysqli_fetch_array($get_colors))
                {
                    $color = explode(",", $get_colors_r["color"]);

                    foreach($color as $color_code)
                    {
                        $color_code = $color_code;
                    }

                    $get_single_color = $filter -> getSingleColor($color_code);

                    while($get_single_color_r = mysqli_fetch_array($get_single_color))
                    {
            ?>
                        <p class="inline1"><button style="background-color:<?php echo $get_single_color_r["color_code"]; ?>; height:25px; width:25px; border:none"></button></p>
            <?php
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove duplicated from an array, you'll need to use PHP's [`array_unique()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

It would work as this according to your code:

```
$color = explode(",", $get_colors_r["color"]); 
$color = array_unique($color);
```

Full simplified example to show how it's working:

```
<?php 
$colors_str = "1,2,1";
$colors_arr = explode(",",$colors_str);
var_dump($colors_arr);
$colors_arr = array_unique($colors_arr);
var_dump($colors_arr);
```

Comment: Can you print the arrays before and after my solution?

Comment: How.. use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` to print the array, not `echo`.

Comment: I've added a simplified example of how it's working.

Comment: before and after same result `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )   Array ( [0] => 1 )`

Comment: Check my example. How is it different from your code? Test it, see what you've done wrong. It must work.

Comment: my first result is `1,2 1`. No comma between last 1.

Comment: That does not make any sense, I get simple integers but what color code would "2 1" represent. Why is data even inserted in the database like this. Jesus.

Comment: I am mixing three table to get this color code. From first table `1,2` and from second table `1`. Thus it becomes `1,2 1`